# create a table based on one row of one to another table

Tags: sql

I created different tables for each authors because each author table has different column names.

Table Author

```
Author_ID   FirstName     LastName 
   1             Rock         Smith       
   2             Edward       Thomas
```

Table Author Books

```
 Author_ID   BookName
   1         Book1
   1         Book2
   1         Book3
   1         Book4
   1         Book5
```

I want result like this
Result Table

```
FirstName   LastName  BookName
 Rock        Smith    Book1
 Rock        Smith    Book2
 Rock        Smith    Book3
 Rock        Smith    Book4
 Rock        Smith    Book4
```

Table New_Authors

```
Author_ID    Author_Table
   1          Rock_Smith
   2          Edward_Thomas
```

Talbe Rock_Smith

```
FirstName   LastName  BookName
 Rock        Smith    Book1
 Rock        Smith    Book2
 Rock        Smith    Book3
 Rock        Smith    Book4
 Rock        Smith    Book4


Is it possible to get all the Rock_Smith table info on querying New_Authors table?
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Nice. Ask a question, get an answer, accept said answer, days later change your question, then when you're told that's bad form mark someone else's answer as accepted. As I told you before, that was incredibly rude.

Comment: Please behave gentleman, I changed the response because the answer he gave was most useful to me. Seems like you like to gather only points instead of helping.

Comment: I asked you for clarification on your original post WHICH YOU NEVER GAVE, tried my best to answer you anyway which APPARENTLY HELPED YOU THEN to which you then CHANGED YOUR QUESTION. I've been around here a lot longer than you. LEARN SITE MANNERS if you want to keep getting help in the future.

Comment: yeah yeah whatever, points man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return the data from those 2 tables, you can run this query:

```
SELECT a.FirstName, A.LastName, b.BookName
FROM Author A inner join AuthorBooks B on A.Author_ID = B.Author_ID
```

If you wanted to create a 3rd table based on the query you would do:

Step 1) Create your Table.

Step 2) Run your query:

```
SELECT a.FirstName, A.LastName, b.BookName
INTO [NewTable]
FROM Author A inner join AuthorBooks B on A.Author_ID = B.Author_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple one to many relationship achieved by a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT a.LastName, a.FirstName, b.BookName
FROM Authors a LEFT JOIN AuthorBooks b ON b.Author_ID = a.Author_ID
ORDER BY LastName, FirstName, BookName
```

Comment: Hello, I edited the question can you please look into it.

Comment: It is not good form to edit your question after you already have an answer. Please figure out how the new question is different from this one and ask a new question. That is the best thing you can do.